# How to use a Superclass and Subclasses in Java with shared methods

Tags: java, generics, subclass

I have a superclass called `Currency` and I want to have a bunch of different subclasses that inherit this super class, e.g. `USD`, `GBP`, `YEN`, etc.

Each of these subclasses have the same attributes and methods. The methods will return the same types of value, but the body of the methods will need to be slightly different. Here's an example (I am using API calls to get the amount of each currency that I own):

```java
    public class USD extends Currency {
        
        public String symbol;
        public String holdings;
        public String bankAccountId; // Each currency has it's own account

        public float getHoldings(String apiKey) {
            HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

            URI uri = new URIBuilder(apiBaseurl)
                .addParameter("module", "account")
                .addParameter("action", "tokenbalance")
                .addParameter("accountid", this.bankAccountId)
                .addParameter("apikey", apiKey)
                .build();
    
            HttpRequest getHoldingsRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(uri)
                .GET()
                .build();
    
            HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(getHoldingsRequest, BodyHandlers.ofString());
    
            ObjectNode node = new ObjectMapper().readValue(response.body(), ObjectNode.class);
    
            return node.get("result").asFloat();
        }
    }
```

My main problem is that I don't want to repeat this `getHoldings()` method in each subclass, so I decided to try and put it into the `Currency` superclass, but then I have 2 new problems:

1. I can't use `this.bankAccountId` in the method (each currency is held in an individual account, specific to that currency and I'd prefer to have the `String bankAccountId` as an attribute for the specific currency subclass).
2. I can't loop through each currency and use the `getHoldings()` method on each one, like this:

```java
    Portfolio portfolio = new Portfolio();
    String myApiKey = "duivbncvavsuivavcshinseo" // Some apiKey here
    
    portfolio.setOwnedCurrencies(Arrays.asList(
        new USD(),
        new GBP(),
        new YEN()    
    ));

    for (Currency currency : portfolio.getOwnedCurrencies()) {
        System.out.println(currency.getHoldings(myApiKey));
    }
```

I've looked at using Generics so I can have `Currency<USD>`, but I can't quite figure out how to use them correctly in this case. I also feel like I'm missing something pretty basic/easy here, but I've been staring at this problem for so long, I just can't see it.

EDIT: I should've mentioned, each `Currency` subclass has other unique values, so each subclass has the same attributes, but the attributes will have different, not just the `bankAccountId`.

Comment: Maybe I am assuming to much on your business model, but it seems to me that it should be "account has its own currency" instead of "Each currency has it's own account", and the portfolio should have its ownedAccounts instead of ownedCurrencies. Maybe I you have a specific model that requires this thought.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use the id through sending it into the method as Ann argument if needed, too, processing of methods by "superclasses extended from" can be package private (should not be public) at worst protected methods (unless you want other classes to be able to access directly), and you could return an array or a Vector if you need to bring back multiple result from the process e.g. bankid and holdings answer.